# Problems with sass-loader and bootstrap in Angular 5

Tags: angular, sass

I am having some issues with my Angular 5, when I try to run `ng serve`.

The issue that is happening is the followig:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false,"import":false}!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib?{"ident":"postcss","sourceMap":false}!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"sourceMap":false,"precision":8,"includePaths":[]}!./src/assets/sass/app.scss
Module build failed:
undefined
         ^
      Argument `$color-2` of `mix($color-1, $color-2, $weight: 50%)` must be a color
      in C:\Users\vinnynordi\Desktop\Projects\mennus\mennus-web\node_modules\bootstrap\scss\_functions.scss (line 103, column 11)
Error:
undefined
         ^
      Argument `$color-2` of `mix($color-1, $color-2, $weight: 50%)` must be a color
      in C:\Users\vinnynordi\Desktop\Projects\mennus\mennus-web\node_modules\bootstrap\scss\_functions.scss (line 103, column 11)
    at options.error (C:\Users\vinnynordi\Desktop\Projects\mennus\mennus-web\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:291:26) @ ./src/assets/sass/app.scss 4:14-206
 @ multi ./node_modules/ng2-dnd/bundles/style.css ./src/styles.scss ./src/assets/sass/app.scss ./src/assets/slick.css ./src/assets/slick-theme.css ./src/assets/calendar.css ./src/assets/notification.css

webpack: Failed to compile
```

I didn't have any problems when installing all `npm` dependencies.

My `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "remeli-web",
  "version": "0.0.2",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check --port 4242 -w --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
    "build": "ng build --env prod --prod --aot",
    "build-homolog": "ng build --env homolog --prod --aot",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm install -D && ng build"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.1.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.3.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.9",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.6.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.6.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0",
    "@ngx-share/core": "^5.3.1",
    "@types/promise.prototype.finally": "^2.0.2",
    "angular-calendar": "^0.23.3",
    "angular2-notifications": "^1.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-beta",
    "compass-mixins": "^0.12.10",
    "core-js": "^2.5.3",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "install": "^0.10.2",
    "mathjs": "^7.0.1",
    "moment": "^2.19.4",
    "ng2-dnd": "^5.0.2",
    "ng2-img-cropper": "^0.9.0",
    "ng2-trim-directive": "^2.1.0",
    "ng2-truncate": "^1.3.11",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^2.0.0",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^0.8.2",
    "ngx-slick": "^0.1.3",
    "npm": "^5.6.0",
    "pretty-checkbox": "^3.0.3",
    "promise.prototype.finally": "^3.1.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.5",
    "ts-md5": "^1.2.2",
    "webpack": "^3.10.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.6.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.2",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.0.58",
    "codelyzer": "~4.0.2",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.5",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.1",
    "protractor": "~5.2.1",
    "ts-node": "~4.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.8.0",
    "typescript": "^2.4.2"
  }
}
```

My `ng version`:

```
Angular CLI: 1.6.6
Node: 10.6.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 5.2.11
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

@angular/cli: 1.6.6
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.0.42
@angular-devkit/core: 0.0.29
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.0.52
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.1.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.9.6
@schematics/angular: 0.1.17
typescript: 2.9.2
webpack: 3.12.0
```

It was working properly before, but I needed to remove and clone the repository again, and after that, it stopped working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try rebuilding node-sass:

```
npm rebuild node-sass --force
```

This error can also be caused by [version](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass#supported-nodejs-versions-vary-by-release-please-consult-the-releases-page--below-is-a-quick-guide-for-minimum-support) mismatch, if nothing works please try downgrading version(4.9+) :

```
npm install node-sass@4.9.4
```